# Calling a function in JS using string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects for example this object:

```
new: {
  name: 'New',
  image: <LightningFilter style={styles.queryImage}/>,
  selectedImage: <LightningWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage}/>,
  dataFunc_Chefs: getNew_Chefs,
  dataFunc_Recipes: getNew_Recipes,
},
```

and I have a variable to check if I am selecting Chefs or Recipes
what I want to do is for example if Chefs is selected call `dataFunc_Chefs` how can I do that using string ?

For example, I want to call this:

```
var category = 'Chefs';
`new.dataFunc_${category}()`
```

I know this doesn't work but this is what I mean

I know I can use if and else and check the variable and call the function accordingly, but lets say I have many functions how do I acheive that

Comment: Looks like this got closed, but you can create a map of functions and use the string input to index. I'll flag to see if we can reopen.

Comment: See @niteesh's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

You just need to access `dataFunc_Chefs` object from your object using string literals.

```js
function getNew_Chefs() {
    console.log('getNew_Chefs executed');
}
function getNew_Recipes() {
    console.log('getNew_Recipes executed');
}
const myObj = {
    name: 'New',
    dataFunc_Chefs: getNew_Chefs,
    dataFunc_Recipes: getNew_Recipes,
}
var category = 'Chefs';
myObj[`dataFunc_${category}`]()
```